# How to properly set up testflight in ios?

Tags: ios6, testflight

I've installed Testflight SDK 1.2.4 for my iOS application. I'm using Xcode version: 4.6. Device: IOS 6.1. Also .ipa and .dSYM were uploaded.

When I run Xcode, it shows following logs:

***TestFlight: Started Session

TestFlight: Crash Handlers are installed

TestFlight: App Token Error  - Your App Token is not recognized https://testflightapp.com

TestFlight: Checkpoint Passed - User_Check_Point

TestFlight: Communication with TestFlight is currently disabled, check earlier in your log for details***

I'm sure App Token is exactly correct.
Also in SDK Debugger there is only session started and ended report;

Here my code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// start of your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
// ...

//#define TESTING 1
//#ifdef TESTING
//    NSUUID *uniqueIdentifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
//    
//    [TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:[uniqueIdentifier UUIDString]];
//#endif
    
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
    // create the signal action structure
    struct sigaction newSignalAction;
    // initialize the signal action structure
    memset(&newSignalAction, 0, sizeof(newSignalAction));
    // set SignalHandler as the handler in the signal action structure
    newSignalAction.sa_handler = &SignalHandler;
    // set SignalHandler as the handlers for SIGABRT, SIGILL and SIGBUS
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGILL, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &newSignalAction, NULL);

    [TestFlight takeOff:@"my_app_token"];

    // The rest of your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method
}
```

Where is my error?! Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've fixed(Problem with cookies)! Thanks for attention.

Comment: Just had the same problem - going from old token to newer app token method.  Can you explain how you fixed yours?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with iOS 7.0.4 and TestFlight SDK version 2.2.1, it was fixed by selecting the correct Team on the app target in XCode's General tab and also the correct provisioning profile and code signing identity on Build Settings.